# Calling spring boot rest service from GWT

Tags: rest, spring-boot, gwt

I want the gwt app to call a spring boot rest service with basic authentication which consumes and produces a json object and is deployed on a seperate server from the gwt app.

Any hints on how this can be done ?

Comment: You can use the GWT classes. Guide can be found here: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideHttpRequests You might have to enable CORS for your spring boot application and also set the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' when doing httprequests from the gwt client.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called [restygwt](https://resty-gwt.github.io/) to easily define REST calls. I think there is an easy way to set the 'Basic' header.